# Given rotor and curve find circulation of a vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, stokes-theorem

**Given the curve $C$ of equation $$\vec X=(3\cos t,3\sin t,6\cos t),\qquad0\leq t\leq2\pi$$ oriented according imposes this parameterization, find the circulation of $\vec f$ along $C$ if $\vec f\in\mathcal C^1$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and $$\text{rot }\vec f(x,y,z)=(0,2x-y,z),$$ where $\text{rot}$ means [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)).**

---

First I found the curve: $$\begin{cases}x=3\cos t\\y=3\sin t\\z=6\cos t\end{cases}\equiv\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=9\\z=6\dfrac x3\end{cases}\equiv\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=9\\z-2x=0,\end{cases}$$ so the normal becomes $$\vec N=(-2,0,1).$$ Now I have to use the Stokes theorem, that is

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\oint\limits_C{\vec f\;\text d\vec s}&(1)\\\\
&=&\iint\limits_S{\Big.\nabla\times\vec f\Big|_S\;\text d\vec\sigma}&(2)\\\\
&=&\iint\limits_{P_{xy}}{(0,2x-y,\underbrace z_{2x})\cdot(-2,0,1)\;\text dx\text dy}&(3)\\\\
&=&2\iint\limits_{P_{xy}}{x\;\text dx\text dy}&(4)\\\\
&\underset{\text{Using polar coordinates}}{=}&2\int_0^{2\pi}{\text d\theta}\int_0^3{\rho\cdot\rho\cos\theta\;\text d\rho}&(5)\\\\
&=&2\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos\theta\;\text d\theta}\int_0^3{\rho^2\;\text d\rho}&(6)\\\\
&=&2\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos\theta\;\text d\theta}\;\left.\left(\frac{\rho^3}3\right)\right|_0^3&(7)\\\\
&=&18\Big.\left(\sin\theta\right)\Big|_0^{2\pi}&(8)\\\\
\text{Circulation}&=&\boxed 0.&(9)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: By “$\operatorname{rot}$” do you mean curl?

Comment: Sorry the misunderstanding. Yes, by $\text{rot}$ I mean the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)).

Comment: There was no particular reason to substitute $z=2x$. $\iint z\,dx\,dy$ is just as good. Either way, you can stop at that point and immediately conclude that the value is $0$ because you’re integrating one cycle of $\cos t$ times some constant.

Comment: Hm, if we are in $xy$-plane why we should not keep $x$ and $y$ variables, and replace $z=z(x)$ or $z=z(y)$ or $z=z(x,y)$?

Comment: Because we are in $xy$ proyection, so anything that has nothing to do with $xy$-plane we should convert it in terms of $x,y$ variables.

Comment: You can certainly proceed that way. On the other hand, since you’ve already got a parameterization of the boundary, in terms of $t$ you can pass directly to the $r$-$t$ plane from $d\sigma$ after computing the dot product of $\nabla\times f$ and the plane normal. The integrand will be $\cos t$ times some function of $r$, and the integral vanishes because you’re integrating over $0\le t\le2\pi$, so there’s no need to even work through all of the details of the pullback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re reached the correct answer, but I think you’ve done more work than you really needed to to get there.

First off, you can compute the surface normal directly from the parametric equation for the curve. Take two convenient points on it, say, at $t=0$ and $t=\pi/2$ and compute their cross product: $(3,0,6)\times(0,3,0)=(-18,0,9)$, which normalizes to $\vec N = \frac1{\sqrt5}(-2,0,1)$. I might also verify that $\vec N\cdot\vec X=0$ for all values of $t$ to be sure that I’m dealing with a planar curve.

You then have $\vec N\cdot\vec f = \frac1{\sqrt5}z=\frac6{\sqrt5}\cos t$, at which point you’re basically done. The region enclosed by the curve can be parameterized as $r\vec X(t)$ for $0\le r\le 1$, which makes the region of integration in the $r$-$t$ plane the rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,2\pi]$. The integrand will be some function of $r$ times $\cos t$, and its integral over a full cycle of $\cos t$ will vanish.